# Storing VARBINARY in a VARCHAR column

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

Please go through this code:

```
DECLARE @EncryptedPassword VARBINARY(8000) = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('ABCD','password')
DECLARE @Setting AS TABLE (ID INT, Value VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @Setting VALUES (1, 'true')
INSERT INTO @Setting VALUES (2, @EncryptedPassword)

SELECT * FROM @Setting
```

`@Setting` table can contain data with multiple data types. As I can see, its storing the value. But cannot retrieve it using `SELECT` command. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @EncryptedPassword, 2)` will give you a hexstring, which can be converted back in much the same way.

Comment: Please reconsider this design. Making everything *stringly* typed makes things "simpler" right up until you retrieve a setting that *should* be an `int` (or here, the `varbinary`) and you find some completely inappropriate string there instead. Consider making your individual settings *columns* instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, I'd strongly recommend that you pivot your settings table and stop stingly-typing everything:

```
DECLARE @EncryptedPassword VARBINARY(8000) = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('ABCD','password')
DECLARE @Setting AS TABLE (
    Lock char(1) not null default 'X' primary key check (Lock='X'),
    SomethingBoolean bit not null,
    Password varbinary(8000) not null)

INSERT INTO @Setting (SomethingBoolean, Password) VALUES
(1,@EncryptedPassword)

SELECT * FROM @Setting
```

Results:

```
Lock SomethingBoolean Password
---- ---------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
X    1                0x02000000588C2EB2C67DED10B7828C05500008DB1B1E53EFF63168EC607CA80CA2A1147B75F0A9D50F6B95C810D6DCED37AE8186
```

This means that settings are actually stored with the *correct data type*. Not only can we rely on type and null checks to ensure settings are correct, we can also apply individual `CHECK` constraints if required on individual settings.

(`Lock` is just there to ensure that this table contains 1 row only)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change The Table Structure and While retrieving DECRYPT Value try to convert into Varbinary column Nvarchar.ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE OR DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE require 2 or more paramter to give you result

```
DECLARE @Setting AS TABLE (ID INT,Value VARBINARY(8000))

INSERT INTO @Setting 
SELECT 1,ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password',N'ABCD')

SELECT * FROM @Setting
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password',Value)) FROM @Setting
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add encryption flag:

```
DECLARE @EncryptPhrase NVARCHAR(100) = 'ABCD'

DECLARE @Setting AS TABLE (ID INT, Value NVARCHAR(MAX), IsEncrypted BIT)

INSERT INTO @Setting VALUES (1, 'true',  0)
INSERT INTO @Setting VALUES (2, ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@EncryptPhrase,N'password'), 1)

SELECT * FROM @Setting

SELECT 
ID
,CASE 
    WHEN IsEncrypted = 1 THEN CAST(DecryptByPassPhrase(@EncryptPhrase, CAST(Value AS VARBINARY(MAX))) as NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
    ELSE Value 
END
FROM @Setting
```